# The procedure entry point NET_DVR_RealPlay_V40 could not be located in the dynamic link library HCNetSDK.dll

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I use c++ dll in my Delphi program and import function off dll like this :

```
function  NET_DVR_RealPlay_V40(lUserID: LongInt;var lpPreviewInfo: LPNET_DVR_PREVIEWINFO; fRealDataCallBack_V30:REALDATACALLBACK;pUser:Pointer): LongInt;stdcall; external 'HCNetSDK.dll' name'NET_DVR_RealPlay_V40';
```

this is c++ code:

```
LONG NET_DVR_RealPlay_V40(  LONG                     lUserID,
  LPNET_DVR_PREVIEWINFO     lpPreviewInfo,
  REALDATACALLBACK          fRealDataCallBack_V30,
  void                     *pUser,);
```

but when running my program show this error:
The procedure entry point NET_DVR_RealPlay_V40 could not be located in the dynamic link library HCNetSDK.dll
I think don't exist this function in dll so that use dependency walker to find this function in dll, result of that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W89Um.png)
I don't know where is my problem

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that the DLL does not export a function with that name. Some possible causes:

- You made a mistake in transcribing the name. Remember that letter case is significant here.
- The function is exported with a decorated or mangled name.

Use a tool like dumpbin or Dependency Walker to check the names of the exported functions, and debug from there.

As an aside, the C++ function declaration makes it look like `cdecl` is the calling convention.

Comment: that is the c++ code:LONG NET_DVR_RealPlay_V40(  LONG                     lUserID,
  LPNET_DVR_PREVIEWINFO     lpPreviewInfo,
  REALDATACALLBACK          fRealDataCallBack_V30,
  void                     *pUser,);

Comment: Did you follow my advice yet? Do you understand what the error message is telling you?

Comment: I konw that you say error is because of parameter or function name , or because that no exist this function but i run this project in c++ and use this function

Comment: *Use a tool like dumpbin or Dependency Walker to check the names of the exported functions, and debug from there.*

Comment: @saharghodsbin execute in console: `tdump HCNetSDK.dll >hc.txt` and find your function in exports section. Look at it's export name (decorated)

Comment: @saharghodsbin: C++ compilers often mangle names, i.e. they add a lot of stuff to the name to make it easier for importers to get the parameters etc. The C++ compiler knows this and can then reduce that to a normal name again. But if such mangled names are exported from DLLs, you will have to find out what it is.

Comment: i find it   NET_DVR_API LONG __stdcall NET_DVR_RealPlay_V40(LONG lUserID, LPNET_DVR_PREVIEWINFO lpPreviewInfo, REALDATACALLBACK fRealDataCallBack_V30 = NULL, void* pUser = NULL);

Comment: I'm not sure it's worthwhile my saying any more. You've ignored everything that I said. Do you want help or not? If you want help, please listen. If you'd rather try to work it all out for yourself, and you don't want our advice, please just delete the question. If you don't understand what we are telling you, please say so. So, let's see if we can be third time lucky. *Use a tool like dumpbin or Dependency Walker to check the names of the exported functions, and debug from there.*

Comment: The name in the header file is not the same as the name exported from the DLL. Find out what the real exported name is. Do what David said. C++ adds a lot of stuff to the name, and can read it from a DLL again. Other compilers, like Delphi, need the actual really exported name.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't know how to use Dependency Walker

Comment: Run the program. Load your DLL. Look at the list of exported functions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanks for your advice but i load dll in dependency walker and find this function in dll and put that image in my post, i don't know where is my problem

Comment: Your executable file is not linked against that DLL. If it were it would not produce the error that you report.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, if it weren't linked , the login function  wouldn't work,but it works.

Comment: Clearly you are linking to a different DLL. You likely have multiple copies of the DLL on your machine and are not linking to the one you expect. The error message that is reported could hardly be less clear. Run the executable under Dependency Walker's profile mode and it will tell you the full path of the DLL that is being linked.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ,when choose function of dll in dependency walker profile starting disable .

Comment: You cannot profile a DLL. You have to profile an executable. That is explained in the FAQ and can easily be found by web search. I have a feeling that you are not trying hard enough to solve the problems by yourself, and when you hit a road block you give up immediately and ask here. You might find this rude, but I strongly suggest that you try harder, and stop giving up so readily.